# Bootstrap IP to internal address conversion

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka and I setup an instance in aws. runs well.
then I **created another aws instance and run the codes**:

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOuJ8.png)

it can print out messages that I published to kafka

**If I ran the same codes in the kafka server itself, I can also get messages.**

However, **if I run the same codes in my own laptop, I cant get anything.**

I thought it might be the codes so I used kafka's own client in my laptop:

`bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic test22 --bootstrap-server 34.215.180.111:9092`

Now I got an error:

2021-05-11 16:21:32,252] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-94326-1, groupId=console-consumer-94326] Error connecting to node **ip-172-31-29-222.us-west-2.compute.internal:9092** (id: 0 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

`ip-172-31-29-222.us-west-2.compute.internal`

this piece of name is actually the AWS instance's internal address:

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtaFQ.png)

Then I thought it might be Amazon's issue so I repeated the whole process in Google Cloud and got the same results:

[2021-05-11 17:15:34,840] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-2377-1, groupId=console-consumer-2377] Error connecting to node **instance-1.us-central1-a.c.seventh-seeker-267203.internal**:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

These internal addresses can not be accessed from external computers at all.
Can anybody help? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The logs are showing you the `advertised.listeners` of the brokers. If you want that to be different  in order to connect, you'll need to modify that property such that the brokers have resolvable addresses for the clients

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/